# Can't access cohort data with segment defined through the API v4

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to access data with cohort dimensions using the Python code below:

```
return analytics.reports().batchGet(
    body={
      'reportRequests': [
      {
        'viewId': VIEW_ID, 
        'metrics': [
          {"expression": "ga:cohortActiveUsers"},
          {"expression": "ga:cohortTotalUsers"}
        ],
        "dimensions":
          [
            {
              "name": "ga:segment"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:cohort"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:cohortNthDay"
            }
          ],
        "segments": [
          {
            "dynamicSegment":
              {
                "name": "Sessions from Poznan",
                "userSegment":
                  {
                    "segmentFilters": [
                      {
                        "simpleSegment":
                          {
                            "orFiltersForSegment":
                              {
                                "segmentFilterClauses": [
                                  {
                                    "dimensionFilter":
                                      {
                                        "dimensionName": "ga:city",
                                        "operator": "EXACT",
                                        "expressions": ["Poznan"]
                                      }
                                  }]
                              }
                          }
                      }]
                  }
              }
          }],
        "cohortGroup": {
          "cohorts": [{
            "name": "cohort 1",
            "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
            "dateRange": {"startDate": "2016-05-10", "endDate": "2016-05-10"}
          }, {
            "name": "cohort 2",
            "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
            "dateRange": {"startDate": "2016-05-10", "endDate": "2016-05-10"}
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
).execute()
```

When I execute this code I receive error `Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together`. However when `segments` section is removed everything works fine.

What is the cause of such error? How should I request such data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific report, as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohort_and_lifetime_value_ltv_dimensions_and_metrics:

there is not the dimension "ga:segment" to be used as a dimension in your cohort report. You should restrict yourself to the dimensions and metrics mentioned in the documentation for the cohort & lifetime reports.

Hope this helps.